# Storing Cookie Data from Table to 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a html table that takes in both string and int data - I want to set a cookie on this table and then store the data to a 2d array so that I can then repopulate the table with this data. So far I have this which sets the cookie but I would like to do with an array instead .

```
 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function saveTable() {

    var data = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
           data += table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML + ",";
       }
     }
     data = table.rows.length + "," + table.rows[0].cells.length + "," + data.substring(0, data.length); // remove the last extra ","
      setCookie("marks", data, 60);
      alert("Cookie Saved");
}
```

Comment: I recommend you try [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), it's much easier.

Comment: Thanks Steeve but need to figure this out in plain old javascript - no jQuery etc

Comment: Okay, then maybe serializing your array as json could be a solution.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for reply but no json either .